# Regular Expression Web Safety

Tags: regex, security

I have an imaging library that accepts querystring parameters to manipulate images dynamically and I use regular expressions to parse the parameters to determine what methods to run on the passed image.

For all my other filters I have very strict expressions to ensure that the processor will only try to act upon definite pattern matches but for one method "Watermark" the expression is broken down into smaller parts as it's far too large and messy to play with on it's own and because each of the possible matches are optional.

My worry is that the parent Regex `watermark=[^&]*` that makes the initial match is far too lax and will open me up to XXS attacks.

What would be a better way to do this? Should I simply bite the bullet and create one massive expression or is there a better alternative?

The an example string I am parsing:

**yourimage?watermark=test|color-fff|size-36|style-italic|opacity-80|position-30-150|shadow-true|font-arial**

My expressions:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex QueryRegex = new Regex(@"watermark=[^&]*",
                                                     RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for the text attribute.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex TextRegex = 
                                  new Regex(@"text-[^/:?#\[\]@!$&'()*%\|,;=]+",
                                            RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for the position attribute.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex PositionRegex = new Regex(@"position-\d+-\d+",
                                                        RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for the color attribute.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex ColorRegex = 
                                      new Regex(@"color-([0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}",
                                                RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for the fontsize attribute.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex FontSizeRegex = new Regex(@"size-\d{1,3}",
                                                        RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for the fontstyle attribute.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex FontStyleRegex = 
                 new Regex(@"style-(bold|italic|regular|strikeout|underline)",
                           RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for the font family attribute.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex FontFamilyRegex = 
                              new Regex(@"font-[^/:?#\[\]@!$&'()*%\|,;=0-9]+",
                                        RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for the opacity attribute.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex OpacityRegex = 
                                new Regex(@"opacity-(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])",
                                          RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// The regular expression to search strings for the shadow attribute.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex ShadowRegex = new Regex(@"shadow-true",
                                                      RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just restrict it to the characters you do accept, instead of the ones you're trying to block? As of your example, most of them are alphanumeric, plus some characters (like "-" and "|"). For example `watermark=[a-zA-Z0-9\-\|]*` would have the same effect, unless you expect a free-text param.

As for the XSS prevention, it also depends on how you use the matched text, if the mask is too open (like the TextRegex), simply escape it before placing on commands, SQL queries and so.

Comment: I see where you are coming from there but the only reason I am blocking the ampersand character with the first regex is that it acts as a delimiter between querystring properties. Everything else should go through. I'll look at more positivity for some of the others though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter at all whether you use one regex or multiple ones.  What matters is that you adequately check the input before you use it in a manner that could open a vulnerability.  As long as you apply all of these regexes before using the input in any way, it is no more vulnerable than doing it all in one step.

In this case, I think a multiple-regex approach is clearly superior.  A single regex would be far too complicated and confusing (especially if the parameters can come in a variable order).    The clearer your code is, the less likely you are to make a mistake that leads to a security problem.

I don't see anything inherently wrong with your regexes, though I do agree with Capilé that you should probably state positively what you want to allow rather than disallowing a large list of special characters.

The ultimate answer depends on how they are used in your code, though.

Comment: I think you are right. Everything is carefully restricted further down the pipe. So I should be fine. I thought this might be the case but a second opinion was needed to be sure. Thanks. I'll look into more positive regex's also.